# How to use use two external resets in FPGA: System Reset and MicroController Reset (GPIO Pin)?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am working with a board that has a XC7A35T.  The person who previously developed the hardware and the code for the board used the same external active low system reset for the micro and the FPGA.  The problem is that the external active low system reset has no affect on the FPGA immediately after power is applied because the external active low system reset has already went high before the configuration memory is loaded.  A microcontroller is connected to the FPGA and there are some spare microcontroller GPIOs that can be used in combination with the active low system reset, but I am sure how to correctly combine them.

The external active low system reset is named SYSTEM_RESET_AL in the FPGA code.  This reset is used by the FPGA as follows (I am only just showing a few of the PS_AL_RESET1).

(* dont_touch = "true" *) IBUFG CMP_IBUFG_01 (.I(SYSTEM_RESET_AL), .O(PS_AL_RESET1)); //High = Normal Operation , Low = Reset

(* dont_touch = "true" *) IBUFG CMP_IBUFG_02 (.I(PS_AL_RESET1), .O(PS_AL_RESET2)); //High = Normal Operation , Low = Reset

(* dont_touch = "true" *) IBUFG CMP_IBUFG_03 (.I(PS_AL_RESET1), .O(PS_AL_RESET3)); //High = Normal Operation , Low = Reset

Given the GPIO is referenced as DSPIO1, Is the following the correct way to code it?

wire DSPIO1_RESET_AL_AND_SYSTEM_RESET_AL;

assign  DSPIO1_RESET_AL_AND_SYSTEM_RESET_AL = DSPIO1 & SYSTEM_RESET_AL ;

(* dont_touch = "true" *) IBUFG CMP_IBUFG_01 (.I( DSPIO1_RESET_AL_AND_SYSTEM_RESET_AL), .O(PS_AL_RESET1)); //High = Normal Operation , Low = Reset

I also added code to the microcontroller to toggle DSPIO1 (low,wait 100us, then high) after the FPGA configuration loaded.

Some FPGA functions stopped working after I added the above code.

What am I doing wrong? (old reset and new reset schematics are shown below)

Is there a better way?

Stephen

[image: New Reset]

[image: Old Reset]

Comment: I've just had a quick look at the data sheet for [XC7A35T](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug470_7Series_Config.pdf) with regard to signals `PROGRAM_B`, `INIT_B`, `FCS_B`, `CSI_B`, `RDWR_B` and `DONE`. May be you could used external hardware to latch (and pulse-stretch) the reset signal until `DONE` goes high.

Answer (score 0):

Given that in the original design the reset was never asserted (while the FPGA was programmed), my guess is that the reset logic in the design has bugs. E.g. there could be things that can't handle an asynchronous reset and are getting stuck in a bad state.

Another possibility is that the original design is fragile and relied on the reset being on the clock network (suggested by the dont_touch IBUFGs), but your combined reset isn't. I'm surprised it let you put an IBUFG on something that's not an input pin. Did you get a warning about that?